# Unix O_CREAT flag without mode specified

Tags: c, unix

The definition of the UNIX *open()* function when used with the O_CREAT flag is that it requires a third argument named *mode* in order to set the files' privileges.

What if that *mode* is not specified?

```
int file;
static const char filename[] = "test.test";

if ((file = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)) == 1)
{
    perror("Error opening file.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

close(file);
```

What happens with the file that is created using those flags?  On my system I get:

```
-r--r-s---  1 hyperboreean hyperboreean     0 2009-02-25 01:40 test.test
```

A theory is that the open function looks on the stack and checks for the mode parameter and ends up using a random integer it finds.

What does the standard say about this?

Comment: This is why function prototypes were invented.

Comment: Your comment does not make sense.

Comment: It does not, indeed. And neither did the downvote.

Comment: FWIW, the open function is overloaded so it can accept two or three arguments.

Comment: The term "overloaded", as far as I recall, did not exist prior to the advent of C++. In C, there can only be one implementation of a function.

Comment: @David: the number and types of the open()'s function arguments may vary - which probably is not the case here, but I don't think we can talk about overloading in C.

Answer (score 8):

The POSIX standard (IEEE 1003.1:2008) prototypes `open()` as:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

The section describing the behaviour of `O_CREAT` doesn't say what will happen if you omit the necessary third argument, which means the behaviour is undefined - anything is possible.

In practice, the use of part of the stack that was intended to be stack frame or return address or something similar is quite likely - unto a reasonable approximation, that can be considered a random integer.

The [POSIX 2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) standard has some interesting new (and useful) flags for `open()`, including:

- `O_FDCLOEXEC` to specify close-on-exec at open.
- `O_DIRECTORY` to specify that the file must be a directory.
- `O_NOFOLLOW` to specify not to chase symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The `mode` value will be modified by the `umask` of the process. So if you don't pass a `mode` explicitly to `open` in an `O_CREAT` operation, and if this results in random bits being used for the mode, those random bits will be modified by the `umask`.

Wish I could be more definitive and precise, but I agree with cdonner that "random" values are being used, along with the `umask`.

Edit: One thing you could try is to use dtruss or truss or some other facility to trace system calls, and look at the value of `mode` at run-time to see if something sensible is used, or if it's just random bits modified by the `umask`, for example.

Comment: In my test using ptrace(), It's just something seemingly random, though in my case it's always an 11-bit (12 bits with the leading 0 to denote octal) number that starts with 2777.

Comment: The 02777 value is interesting because it implies world writable with the set-gid bit. Well, just another reason why creating a file without the mode is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

hyperboreean, your suspicion may be not so far off the mark. 
I was hoping to find the answer in [Kernighan Ritchie](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/293279/Kerningan-y--Ritchie---The-C-programming-language). Unfortunately, I did not.
I think the permissions parameter is required with the O_CREAT flag, and if you don't provide it, open() will pull a random value from the stack, which of course goes unnoticed in C.

Edit: by "random" I mean not predictable. It probably is picking up part of the return address, which sits on top of the parameters on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, on most libc systems, you will probably be on hands of [**va_arg**, which states in it's man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html):

> ```
>    If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the
>    type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the
>    default argument promotions), **random errors will occur**.
> ```

```
int
__libc_open64 (const char *file, int oflag, ...)
{
    int mode = 0;

    if (oflag & O_CREAT)
    {
        va_list arg;
        va_start (arg, oflag);
        mode = va_arg (arg, int);
        va_end (arg);
    }

    if (SINGLE_THREAD_P)
        return INLINE_SYSCALL (open, 3, file, oflag | O_LARGEFILE, mode);

    int oldtype = LIBC_CANCEL_ASYNC ();

    int result = INLINE_SYSCALL (open, 3, file, oflag | O_LARGEFILE, mode);

    LIBC_CANCEL_RESET (oldtype);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

> ...open()... O_CREAT flag...
>   What if that *mode* is not specified?

In addition to other people's answers, if you want to future-proof against this by **get**ting **a** ***compiler error*** when you forgot to specify the *mode* flag in those cases where it is needed(ie. *O_CREAT* or *O_TMPFILE*, according to `man 2 open`), you'd have to **use** the *GNU project C and C++ compiler* (eg. the **`gcc`** command) with arg. [**`-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604146/11509478) (or `2`) and an optimization flag eg. `-O1` or the usual **`-O2`** (because `_FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)`).

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
int file;
static const char filename[] = "test.test";

if ((file = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)) == 1)
{
    perror("Error opening file.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

close(file);
}
```

(save that as file: `a.c`)

```
$ gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O1 a.c
In file included from /usr/include/fcntl.h:328,
                 from a.c:3:
In function ‘open’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at a.c:10:13:
/usr/include/bits/fcntl2.h:50:4: error: call to ‘__open_missing_mode’ declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments
    __open_missing_mode ();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So you get: `open with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments`

**Pedantics follow**:
Note that: `-O0` or no `-O` arg. won't work(ie. it won't tell you that you forgot to add `mode` because it's as if `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` was unspecified or simply ignored):

```
$ gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O0 a.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from a.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:382:4: warning: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Wcpp]
 #  warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
    ^~~~~~~
```

Using [`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604146/11509478) will protect you like that for [other cases](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_Features?rd=Security/Features#Compile_Time_Buffer_Checks_.28FORTIFY_SOURCE.29) too, and for `open()` there is one more case: `open can be called either with 2 or 3 arguments, not more`, seen in file `/usr/include/bits/fcntl2.h` as:

```c
__errordecl (__open_too_many_args,
         "open can be called either with 2 or 3 arguments, not more");
__errordecl (__open_missing_mode,
         "open with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments");

__fortify_function int
open (const char *__path, int __oflag, ...)
{
  if (__va_arg_pack_len () > 1)
    __open_too_many_args ();

  if (__builtin_constant_p (__oflag))
    {
      if (__OPEN_NEEDS_MODE (__oflag) && __va_arg_pack_len () < 1)
    {
      __open_missing_mode ();
      return __open_2 (__path, __oflag);
    }
      return __open_alias (__path, __oflag, __va_arg_pack ());
    }

  if (__va_arg_pack_len () < 1)
    return __open_2 (__path, __oflag);

  return __open_alias (__path, __oflag, __va_arg_pack ());
}
```

The reason GNU C Compiler (eg. `gcc`) is needed is, at the very least, because of the following code from file `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h`:

```c
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (4,3)
# define __warndecl(name, msg) \
  extern void name (void) __attribute__((__warning__ (msg)))
# define __warnattr(msg) __attribute__((__warning__ (msg)))
# define __errordecl(name, msg) \                                                                                               
  extern void name (void) __attribute__((__error__ (msg)))
#else
# define __warndecl(name, msg) extern void name (void)
# define __warnattr(msg)
# define __errordecl(name, msg) extern void name (void)
#endif
```

that says that gcc version 4.3 is the minimum required for this to work.
(FYI: my current version is gcc (GCC) 8.3.0)

So if you try `clang` *version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final) Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu*, you don't get the compile error:

```
$ clang -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O1 a.c
```

(no output here even with -, compilation succeeded: *a.out* created)
because this clang version defines `__GNUC__` to be `4` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` to be `2` thus 4.2 is just shy of the 4.3 required for it to work; and forcing eg. 8.3 won't work:

```
$ clang -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -D__GNUC__=8 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=8 -O1 a.c
In file included from <built-in>:355:
<command line>:2:9: warning: '__GNUC__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __GNUC__ 8
        ^
<built-in>:9:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __GNUC__ 4
        ^
In file included from <built-in>:355:
<command line>:3:9: warning: '__GNUC_MINOR__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 8
        ^
<built-in>:7:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 2
        ^
2 warnings generated.
```

The above source codes come from `glibc` 2.29.9000.r269.g1f50f2ad85-1 package on Arch Linux. ie.

```
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h is owned by glibc 2.29.9000.r269.g1f50f2ad85-1
/usr/include/bits/fcntl2.h is owned by glibc 2.29.9000.r269.g1f50f2ad85-1
```

PS: without `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, you can get random modes on each program run, like [I did](https://gist.github.com/howaboutsynergy/4dc0c41d6244d91a7dfd07159b905fe9#gistcomment-2920146):

```
$ ./go
-r-x--s--T 1 user user 0 May 17 17:22 /tmp/broken_perms.log
$ ./go
---sr-s--- 1 user user 0 May 17 17:23 /tmp/broken_perms.log
$ ./go
-rws--x--- 1 user user 0 May 17 17:23 /tmp/broken_perms.log
$ ./go
--wsr-x--T 1 user user 0 May 17 17:23 /tmp/broken_perms.log
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use C macros to catch this problem.

```
#undef open
#define open(a, b, c) open(a, b, c)
```

Now you can't call `open` without three arguments.

This is similar to writing macros for `struct` initializers, to make sure users don't neglect to initialize some members:

```
#define foo_initializer(a, b, c) { .x = (a), .y = (b), .z = (c) }
```

If later we add a new member `w`, we can extend `foo_initializer` with a new argument. When we recompile the code base, the compiler will find all the places where it's only being given three arguments. Whereas "naked" initializers that neglect to initialize `w` will continue to compile cleanly.